# React filter not filtering through objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and have a problem with rendering out some filtered data to a component.

I have data that gets imported into state of a parent `<app/>` container like so:

```
getInitialState () {
    return {
        samples:allSamples,
        searchInputVal:""
    }   
},
```

Here is the data that gets loaded into the samples initial state:

```
export default [
            {
            id:"1",
            sampleName:'Deep House Base',
            sampleFamily:'Deep House Pack',
            parentCategory:"bass",
            subCategory:"house bass",
            uploader:"Ben",
            soundSource:"../../samplesWav/bd_909dwsd.wav",
            tags:[
                "house","ghouse","tech-house","rad"
            ]
        },
            {
            id:"2",
            sampleName:'Deep House Base',
            sampleFamily:'G House Pack',
            parentCategory:"bass",
            subCategory:"house bass",
            uploader:"Ben",
            soundSource:"../../samplesWav/bd_chicago.wav",
            tags:[
                "house","ghouse","tech-house","rad"
            ]
        }
]
```

I have created a header component that is child of `<app/>` with an input to server as a filter function like so:

```
<input placeholder="Search Samples Here..." onChange={this.props.updateSearch} value={this.props.searchInputVal} type="text"></input>
```

onChange it performs the updateSearch function in its parent. This is what that function looks like:

```
updateSearch(event){
    this.setState({
        searchInputVal:event.target.value.substr(0,20)
    })
},
```

Currently when I type letters in the input the state is updating with the value so that part is working fine. It's the part where I render out my objects that isn't filtering. Here is the component I'm trying to filter:

```
class SamplesInnerLrg extends Component {  
    render() {
        let filteredSamples = this.props.loadAllInitSamples.filter(
            (sample) => {
                return sample.sampleFamily.indexOf(
                    this.props.searchInputVal
                )
            }
        )
        return <div className="samples-container-inner-styling">
        {
        console.log(filteredSamples),
        filteredSamples.map((sample) => {
        return (
                <div key={sample.id} className="sample-comp-lge">
                <div className="sample-comp-lge-head-wrap">
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-audio" id={sample.id} ref={sample.id} onClick={this.playSampleAction.bind(undefined,sample,sample.id)}>
                        <audio preload="auto" className="audioTag">
                              <source src={sample.soundSource} type="audio/wav" />
                        </audio>
                    </div>
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-header">
                        <span className="sample-comp-lge-Name"><h1>{sample.sampleName}</h1></span>
                        <span className="sample-comp-lge-id"><h2><a href="#">{sample.sampleFamily}</a></h2></span>
                        <div className="sample-comp-lge-owner-cont">
                            <div className="sample-comp-lge-owner-inner">
                                <a href="">{sample.uploader}</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="sample-comp-lge-bottom-wrap">
                    <div className="sample-comp-lge-tags-cont">
                        <div className="sample-comp-lge-tag">
                            <ul className="sample-tags-list">
                                {
                                    sample.tags.map((tag) => {
                                        return ( 

                                            <li key={tag}><a href="#">#{tag}</a></li>
                                        )
                                    })

                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>
            )
        })
   }
   </div>
    }
}
```

There are two problems here with my render of this component. First of all when I load the page there are no objects being rendered to the DOM but when I starting typing in the input box they suddenly appear. Second, it doesn't matter what I type they will all appear no matter what (I have more than 2 but for the sake of StackOverflow I only included 2). Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
let filteredSamples = this.props.loadAllInitSamples.filter(
        (sample) => {
            return sample.sampleFamily.indexOf(
                this.props.searchInputVal
            )
        }
)
```

...is problematic. `indexOf` returns an index or `-1` if nothing is found. `.filter(...)` expects the function to return a boolean value. You'll want to add a `>= 0` to your index result to convert it to a boolean (assuming you want "is present" to be `true`):

```
const filteredSamples = this.props.loadAllInitSamples.filter(sample => {
  return sample.sampleFamily.indexOf(this.props.searchInputVal) >= 0;
});
```